# Почему получается разница в отображении запускаемой программы, если ее запускать запуская скрипт мышкой, через терминал или в dash (ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, qtcreator, terminal

Ubuntu16.04LTS

1) Запускаю программу через dash

[image: запуск программы через dash]

или кликами мышки
[image: запуск программы мышкой]

Программа отображается так:
[image: вид программы, если ее запустить через dash или мышкой]
2) Если запускать через терминал:
[image: запуск программы в терминале]

То получается вот так:
[image: вид программы, если ее запустить в терминале]

Почему так происходит?

Меня это интересует потому, что если запускать первым способом, то программа глючит, а именно если создать или открыть файл, то меню исчезает (File, Edit, ...) и больше не появляется.

Если же запускать через терминал при помощи sudo, то все отлично работает без всяких глюков. Если же запускать через терминал, но без sudo, то программа работает как в первом случае

Comment: Во втором случае вы запускаете ее из-под root'а, у него свои настройки видимо.

Comment: 1. используйте sudo только для административных задач. 2. исправить последствия бездумного употребления sudo можно так: `$ sudo chown -R $USER $HOME`

Comment: Так если я запускаю программу не используя sudo, то программа на моем компьютере фактически неработоспособна (отсутствуют меню). Перепробовал варианты решения проблемы, найденные в интернете, например удалил appmenu-qt5, но ничего не помогло. Получается, что ли, что без sudo тут не обойтись? Ну и второй совет как раз вовремя пришелся

Comment: @pynix: Вот в этом и проблема, должно работать без sudo. Может, вы неправильно проинсталлирловали qt creator?

Comment: @VladD, вроде бы все правильно делаю: скачиваю qt-creator-opensource-linux-x86_64-4.2.1.run, даю права на иcполнение, запускаю `sudo ./qt-creator-opensource-linux-x86_64-4.2.1.run`, ставится без каких-либо вопросов (или то же самое делаю ставя Qt Creator как часть Qt5). А пока я поставил более старую версию Qt Creator, в ней нет глюков, ей и буду пользоваться, а то и так уже два дня убил что-бы заставить программу Qt Creator4.2.1 заработать.